# Esper and SQS

Tags: cloud, esper, amazon-sqs

I'm wondering if anyone here has tried using Esper to process stuff from the Cloud? Specifically Amazon's Simple Queueing Service. I've googled about this, and we know it's feasible, but it would be nice to know if anyone has tried it. Even better has anyone tried putting Esper into the cloud as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did run Esper in Amazon EC2 cloud - and so did f.e. Strateer who is one of Esper customer.
I haven't tried with SQS but that should be trivial using SQS API.

I also ran Esper in Google App Engine / Java. You'll need to apply few best practices - f.e. turn off internal timer thread and deal with it at the event sender level with time event for example - as Google doesn't allow the application to start threads. Running in Google App Engine can also be problematic if state matters as jvms come and go when Google decides it without control on your side. You might want to consider EsperHA and a specific EsperHA implementation using its SDK to bind it to the Google JPA/JDO implementation for example.